# Android Studio: Rendering Problems when I open a project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am having this issue with Rendering problems every time i open a project.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:192)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:186)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttgj0.png)

I don't know how to fix it permanently, or why this is happening repeatedly.
I read up on it and someone suggested that I Change the theme to the following:
[theme change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDRCv.png)

I did that, and it takes care of the problem for the session, but as soon as i close android studio ad open it back up again, i am greeted by the sae problem.
What am I doing wrong here?
How can I fix this for good?

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

Restart `Android Studio` by invalidating the caches

> File → Invalidate Caches / Restart.

This may fix the issue.
For more information visit this [site](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/harvesthq/chosen/q/stackoverflow/13439486/missing-styles-is-the-correct-theme-chosen-for-this-layout)

**Alternative Solution**

Use a higher `SDK` as the minimum `SDK` like `lollipop` or `marshmallow` when building the project. If you really want to use a lower `SDK` as the minimum `SDK`, start from `blank activity` and develop from there onwards

Comment: @uddinstock try the altenative solution and let me know what happened

Answer (score 0):

on the very first line of your log cat its already telling you

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

follow as it says.

Comment: Ya, I got that earlier but didn't know why. Thanks for the answer, I now know why.
Do you know how to change themes without having any problems like this?